# 2000 Dodge Intrepid electrical problem

Tags: electrical, battery, dodge

I accidently let the battery power cable touch the frame of the car and it sparked. Now my car does not light up dashboard or anything type of power. I tried jumping the car and still no sin of life. I checked the fuses and nothing is blown out. I checked the relays and nothing is blown. Can anybody help? IS it the battery, I just bought this 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

Does the car have a big "master fuse" somewhere in the engine bay? If so, that is probably your culprit... There may also be a second fuse box in the engine bay as well as the main one in the cabin.

If you have access to a multimeter, a decent battery should put out just over 12v when the car is switched off, however I doubt that a quick short like the one you describe would ruin the battery.